# Kotlin secondary constructor never used

Tags: kotlin, oop

I am just learning Kotlin and this is my code

```
  fun main() {
var Vinay = Person(lastName = "Vinay")
        Vinay.hobby = "Play tennis"
        Vinay.stateHobby()
        Vinay.age = 25
        println(" vinay is ${Vinay.age} years old")

    }
    class Person(firstName: String = "Chaitra", lastName: String = "Nadig") {
    
        var age: Int? = null
        var hobby: String = "Coding"
    
    
        init {
            println("Welcome  $firstName $lastName")
        }

        constructor(firstName: String, lastName: String, age: Int)
                : this(firstName, lastName){
            this.age = age
            println("Inside the constructor").  //not getting printed
            println("Person is $firstName $lastName aged $age") //not getting printed
    
        }
    
        fun stateHobby() {
            println("Hobby is $hobby")
        }
    }
```

Nthing inside the construtor is getting printed. It says constructor never called. Kindly help

Comment: Your argument list is just `lastName = "Vinay"`. The only constructor that matches that is the primary constructor. How about `firstName = "Chaitra", lastName = "Vinay", age = 25` instead?

Comment: it means the object we create should have the params that matches the one of the constructor is it

Comment: solved my question. I had assuemed it will take other default values if not specified. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a minor issue in your code

````
fun main(){
        var Vinay=Person("Vinay", "dave", 10)
        Vinay.hobby="Play tennis"
        Vinay.stateHobby()
        Vinay.age=25
        println(" vinay is ${Vinay.age} years old")

        }```

Copy and paste in your function it will work, you just forgot to call 3 params while creating an object. constructor calling is always based on params
````

Comment: Yeah I was thinking same!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by the comment. The params that the constructor takes comes from the instace we create. I had only specified one param in the instance and  my contructor took 3 arguments. It worked after i changed the instance.